# Base tag messing with bookmark links

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a Joomla site which uses `mod_rewrite` to create pretty urls.

```
http://www.example.com/resources/newsletter
```

However this created a problem. Including images like this: `src="images/pic.jpg"`, it would then look for a file at:

```
http://www.example.com/resources/newsletter/images/pic.jpg
```

...which obviously doesn't exist. To work around this, I included a `<base>` tag in my `head` section:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

...which worked fine, until I tried to do a link to an anchor point (bookmark) on the same page:

```
<!-- on http://www.example.com/resources/newsletter -->
<a href="#footer">go to the footer</a>

<!-- clicking that link takes you to http://www.example.com/#footer -->
```

Changing my links to be `<a href="resources/newsletter/#footer">` is not feasible, since I won't necessarily know the URL of the page when editing it. Is there any way to make some links ignore the `<base>` directive?

Though I'd really prefer a straight HTML solution, I'm using jQuery on this site already, so that could be an option if I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to change your `src` attribute to be something like `/images/pic.jpg`? That'll achieve the effect you're looking for.

If that's not possible, this (untested) jQuery code should work for you:

```
$('a[@href^="#"]').click(function() { 
  var hash = this.hash, el = $(hash), offset;
  if(!el.size()) {
    el = $("[@name=" + hash.slice(1) + "]");
  }

  offset = el.offset();
  window.scroll(offset.left, offset.top);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, new answer..
Try this:

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
});
```